# Unity Serializable Class Custom Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I have a very simple class in unity, UnitRange (which has a minimum and a maximum range).

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UnitRange {
    public int Minimum;
    public int Maximum;
}
```

And this shows up in the inspector (if I make a public variable of this type.) Though the default way it is shown isn't very good:

[image]

Now, I was wondering how I can change this? I found how to change the inspector of monobehaviours, though couldn't find how to change it of other classes. I would like it to just be two numbers next to each other, something like this:

[image]

It's just a small thing, and not that big a problem if it's not possible, though knowing how to could prove more useful later too.

Oh yes, as you might have noticed, I'm using c#, so it would be nice if any example code is in c#.

Thanks.

Comment: are there any other types that do this in the inspector? if so, maybe have a look at how they are implemented (in particular, do they have any interesting attributes, interfaces, or custom ToString etc)

Comment: Unity's Vector3 does it in the transform. Though maybe that's just the transform that has a custom inspector to make Vector3 look better. Though Unity isn't open source so you can't see the code of the transform :(

Comment: yes, but surely type metadata is available via reflection? so you should still be able to see attributes and interfaces... it should even be available just in the object browser.

Comment: is there a place where I can find the source stuff, of people who already did that before me, that you know of? Or do I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Unity4 you can make this with [PropertyDrawer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html)

Answer (score 2):

**This is no longer true in later versions of Unity.**

Just found out this is not possible.

The only way to do this is, whenever you use it in a monobehaviour, to give that monobehaviour a custom inspector and in there give the class your custom layout. To make this easier you can  make a method which does the layouting and then use that in each monobehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that would require writing less custom inspectors would be to make `UnitRange` a component. Anything that needs a `UnitRange` you can annotate with `[RequireComponent (typeof (UnitRange))]` so you don't have to go through the hassle of adding it yourself. Make `UnitRange` check it's the only one attached (and error/remove itself etc if it's not).

Then make your various units cache the attached unit range component on `Start()` using `GetComponent<UnitRange>()`, ready for later use (as you currently do, if you just change the visibility to private and reuse).

Finally - write the inspector for UnitRange that looks nice.